# Formulating rigorously the notion of "countable infinite many set-theoretic operations"

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

For algebras generated by a family of sets there is a way to explicitly
describe how this algebra looks like. But my measure-theory lecture
notes tell me, that for $\sigma$-algebras this is not the case anymore
since one can prove that

> the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some family of sets $\mathcal{S}$ is
>   strictly greater that the family of sets that can be constructed by a
>   sequence of countable infinite set-theoretic operation applied to
>   $\mathcal{S}$.

My questions are:

- Since this last assertion to me has a little bit
  of a meta-mathematical flavour (since "countable infinite many
  set-theoretic operations" is not a mathematical object) I would
  like to know how do you formulate it mathematically (if necessary
  in predicate logic) ?
  I believe this may be rather complicated since
  I can't think of an efficient way to describe all sets one can obtain
  this way (we have all countable unions of sets from $\mathcal{S}$
  in it -- but also the set where we successively intersect two sets
  and then take the complement, than intersect with some other two sets
  and take the complement again and so on...this is already pretty cumbersome
  to describe)
- Can you give me a reference for its proof ?

Comment: Are you familiar with transfinite recursion?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker No, I'm not, but I've heard that this is the tool of choice in these situations (do you maybe mean transfinition *induction*?). But isnt't it possible to answer my question without appealing to transfinite recursion/induction ?